# Dynamic sum of row based on two column criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let me start by saying that I've searched before, and I have found similar questions but could not adapt any.

This is the problem:

[image: !(http://i.imgur.com/VoCjP4o.jpg)]

So, for the criteria "a" for c1, "c" for c2, and "m3", the result would be 11. If i would swap m3 for m2 the result would be 6.

The combinations of c1 and c2 are unique.

The result can be found with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="a")*(B2:B5="c");(C2:C5+D2:D5+E2:E5))
```

But I can't make the final sum of columns dynamic...

With an array formula, I can get the result with:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$5="a";IF($B$1:$B$5="c";$C$1:$E$5;0);0))
```

But it doesn't seem to accept offset formula inside the array so that I can make the range dynamic.

Comment: How precisely do you want to "make the ranges dynamic"?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Using the INDEX/MATCH, one can set the extents of a range. Try this:

```
=SUM(INDEX($C$2:$E$5;MATCH(1;IF($A$2:$A$5=H2;IF($B$2:$B$5=I2;1;0);0);0);1):INDEX($C$2:$E$5;MATCH(1;IF($A$2:$A$5=H2;IF($B$2:$B$5=I2;1;0);0);0);MATCH(J2;$C$1:$E$1;0)))
```

This is an Array formula so use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode instead of enter.

[image]